# WireShark lightweight capture, can it be done?

Tags: networking, wireshark

Often when I'm using WireShark, I don't really need to capture the contents of a frame. I'm essentially just making sure that some traffic is flowing, and maybe checking a few flags (FIN ACK etc). Yet the default setting is to capture everything the (filtered) NIC sees, which can fill up my HD pretty fast.

Is there a setting where you can just see the summary lines, without capturing the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't really need to capture the contents of a frame ... I'm essentially just making sure that some traffic is flowing, and maybe checking a few flags (FIN ACK etc)

So you need only the TCP header (and all the packet data that goes before the TCP header).  A typical IPv4 header is 20 bytes long, as is a typical TCP header, so, on an Ethernet, you would typically only need to capture the first 54 bytes of the packet.  For IPv6, the typical header is 40 bytes long, so that, on an Ethernet, you would typically only need the first 74 bytes.  However, the IPv4 and TCP headers *might* have options, and the IPv6 header might have extension headers, so capturing 68 bytes for IPv4 or 96 bytes for IPv4-or-IPv6 might be better

For other networks, you'd have to adjust that value based on the link-layer header length.  For 802.11 when not in monitor mode, you'll probably get "fake Ethernet" headers, so the values that are used for Ethernet will work; for 802.11 in monitor mode, you might have a "radiotap" header or some other "radio metadata" header, so you'd have to look at some captures on your machine to see how big the 802.11 header + the radio metadata header would be.

Once you know the "snapshot length" you should use, you can specify it in the "Limit each packet to [ ... ] bytes" field of the interface options in Wireshark 1.8 and later or in the "Capture Options" dialog prior to 1.8.

Wireshark will still show what packet details it can given the limited amount of packet data that it captured, so you won't see *only* the summary lines.  You will, however, get less data per packet, saving disk space.